# Is Wilcoxon Post Hoc appropriate?

Tags: post-hoc, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have run Friedmans Tests on Likert Scale data sets.  This has allowed me to report on the mean ranks of 8 attributes that are important to individuals when deciding to adopt specialist teaching practices.  1 is not important at all to 5 being highly important. Friedman's says it is significant, and the mean rankings tell me the order of importance for the whole sample BUT....

I have been advised that a Wilcoxon Post Hoc test should be undertaken, but I am struggling to grasp why really.  I have 151 participants and have been told to match the top two mean ranked attributes and the bottom two ranked attributes and run these.  So I would have 12 pairs e.g. Students centred to age, student centred to training, students centred to cost and then age to student centred, age to training, age to cost and so on.

Is this going to add any value and what happens if one or two sets within a category are insignificant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will probably be helpful to conduct post-hoc testing.

One approach appropriate for Friedman is Conover test.  Another approach is pairwise sign tests with a p-value correction for multiple tests.  The Wilcoxon test you mention may be the paired rank sum test.  This makes sense as a post-hoc test, although my understanding is that Friedman is more like an extended sign test, leaving the paired rank sum test somewhat of a mismatch for Friedman.

While the Friedman test told you that there is a difference among attributes, it doesn't tell you which attributes are different than which others.  This is what the post-hoc test is for.  For example, let's say Student-centered and Age were the top two attributes, and let's say Student-centered was numerically higher.  It is still a question whether they are statistically different or not.  If they are not statistically different, then there isn't good evidence to treat one as higher than the other.